# Computation of the remainder term on a Taylor expansion using contour integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I am not really used to the methods of complex analysis, I would like to know for basic  monotonic functions like exp(x), log(x), sqrt(x), powers (x^n) and trigonometric functions defined on an real interval, is it possible to use explicit contour integrals (in the complex plane) to compute rigorous bounds which are sharper than those obtained via the Lagrange remainder?. I think in many cases a Cauchy Estimate (which can be computed analytically) can be sharper than the Lagrange form evaluated over the whole interval, especially when computing higher order expansions of functions whose derivatives tend to grow (e.g. 1/x).

Thanks in advance.